# GPUImage2 and Kaleidoscope CIFilter

Tags: ios, swift, gpuimage, cifilter

I want to add a layer containing a kaleidoscope generated via CIFilter on top of a video which is processed via GPUImage and save those two layers to a single video file.

I already have the processing and saving implemented with GPUImage2, now I want to figure out adding this video overlay created with that CIFilter

Looking the GPUImage doc, I did not see any obvious pointer as to how to do this.
Any pointers appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using CIFilter for everything as I found a chroma key filter on online